# How to disable SQL server 2012 sa password auto Reset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have SQL server 2012 in windows xp and we using sa login and password as null.
My problem is the password automatically reset within 3 hours once,
Anyone can help how to disable the automatically reset password or how to increase the reset time.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but for starters have a look at the properties of the sa login and look at both the following checkboxes:
Enforce Password Policy
Enforce Password Expiration

HAVING A NULL PASSWORD IS A VERY BAD IDEA

The sa login should have a STRONG password
You shouldn't be using sa login for normal day-to-day stuff - set up user specific logins.